# Shifting the elements of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to shift the elements of an array cyclically so all elements are replaced with the previous element, and the last rotates to the first poaition, like so:

```py
shift(1, [5, 6, 7]) => [7, 5, 6]
```

The following code only returns `[7,5]`. Could someone please tell me what is causing this to happen? I went through the code step by step and simply could not find a solution. I also tried 3 different interpreters.

```py
def shift(key, array):
    counter = range(len(array)-1)
    new = counter
    for i in counter:
        new[i] = array[i-key]
    return new

print shift(1, [5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Since `counter` has one fewer element than `array`, and `new` points to the same list as `counter`, and you are returning `new`, what you are returning is  going to have one less element than the original list.

Answer (score 13):

`range(5)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. It excludes `5`.

Just remove the `-1` from `range(len(array)-1)` and it should work.

You could also use list slicing:

```
def shift(key, array):
    return array[-key:] + array[:-key]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the python way:

```
def shift(key, array):
    return array[-key:]+array[:-key]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `-1` from your range:

```
counter = range(len(array))
```

If you want a faster method though,
You could instead try using a deque?

```
from collections import deque

def shift(key, array):
    a = deque(array) # turn list into deque
    a.rotate(key)    # rotate deque by key
    return list(a)   # turn deque back into a list


print (shift(1, [5, 6, 7]))
```

Comment: That helped a lot esp the suggestion to use deque and how to convert deque back into a list.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are good, but it doesn't work if the key is greater than the length of the array.  If you think the key will be larger than the array length, use the following:

```
def shift(key, array):
    return array[key % len(array):] + array[:key % len(array)]
```

A positive key will shift left and a negative key will shift right.

Answer (score 1):

The **numpy** package contains the **roll** function to perform exactly this task:

```
import numpy as np
b=[5,6,7]
c=np.roll(b,1).tolist()

>>> c
[7, 5, 6]
```

A function using this and returning a list is:

```
def shift(array,key):
    return np.roll(array,key).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ashift(key,array):
        newqueue = array[-key:]
        newqueue.extend( array[:-key] )
        return newqueue


print ashift( 1, [5,6,7] )
print ashift( 2, [5,6,7] )
```

Results in:

```
$ ./shift 
[7, 5, 6]
[6, 7, 5]
```

The only potential penalty is if the array is sufficiently large, you may encounter memory issues, as this operation is doing a copy. Using a "key" with an absolute value greater than the length of the array will result in wrapping and results may not be as expected, but will not error out.

Answer (score 0):

Good old fashioned POP & APPEND

```
arr = [5, 6, 7]

for _ in range(0, 2):
    shift = arr.pop(0)
    arr.append(shift)

print(arr)

=>[7, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> np.roll(x, 2)
array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> np.roll(x, -2)
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```